# AngularJS remove # for an app built in wordpress

Tags: angularjs, wordpress

I have inherited a project with an AngularJS, version 1.4, app that lives inside wordpress. Recently I have been asked to remove # from the app generated content. I can remove the # using html5Mode(true). It works on the archive page and when I access job details from there. But going directly to a detail page or reloading it, the job details crash. When I put the # back I can easily access the job detail from anywhere, which is essential.

I have also tried to update my .htaccess with all sorts of different rewrites I got from here on SO, but none of them make any difference.

Have you had a similar experience with this? Anything I am doing obviously wrong when you see the code?

Here is my config for angular.

```
;(function() {

angular.module('jobFeed')
.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', 
'cfpLoadingBarProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, cfpLoadingBarProvider) 
{

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

        $stateProvider
        .state('list', {
            url: '/?jtype&department',
            controller: 'listController',
            controllerAs: 'listCtrl',
            templateUrl: templatesPath + 'list.template.html',
            resolve: {
                getPageData : ['CustomFields', 
                    function getPageData(CustomFields) {
                        return CustomFields.getCustomFields();
                    }
                ]
            }
        })
        .state('detail', {
            url: '/detail/:id',
            controller: 'detailController',
            controllerAs: 'detailCtrl',
            templateUrl: templatesPath + 'detail.template.html',
            resolve: {
                getPageData : ['CustomFields', 
                    function getPageData(CustomFields) {
                        return CustomFields.getCustomFields();
                    }
                ]
            }
        });

        cfpLoadingBarProvider.parentSelector = '#loading';
        cfpLoadingBarProvider.spinnerTemplate = '<div class="vbox-overlay"><div class="vbox-preloader"></div></div>';
    }
]); 

})();
```

Also I have added the base meta tag in the header so that renders properly.

Comment: Have you checked this [post](https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/)

Comment: Yep, already tried this one. No luck. The app I have is inside wordpress, it's not a root level app and the url points to career/jobs. All of the solutions I see around are for standalone angularjs apps.

Comment: If you could make the `list` state url like `/list/?jtype&department`, then the app will have a better idea where to go, could you please try this?

Comment: Hi @NarenMurali, thanks for the suggestion, it didn't make much difference apart from stopping the page to load completely. The main issue here is in the details pages, somehow if you go to them directly they throw up 404, the list is working fine.